# BZip2 file read in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, gzip, mapper, bzip2

I heard we can use multiple mappers to read different parts of one bzip2 file in parallel in Hadoop, to increase performance. But I cannot find related samples after search. Appreciate if anyone could point me to related code snippet. Thanks.

BTW: is gzip has the same feature (multiple mapper process different parts of one gzip file in parallel).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.lucene.hadoop.user/30662, 
you will find that bzip2 format is indeed splittable and multiple mappers can work on one file. The patch was submitted at: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-4012. However, it seems it is available only above HADOOP 0.21.0.

From personal experience in order to use this technique of bzip2 there is nothing different that you need to do. hadoop should pick it up automatically depending on your min split size.

bzip2 compressed data by blocks and therefore it is possible to decompress it in blocks and send each block to a separate mapper. However, gzip does not have such a technique and therefore this cannot be sent to different mappers.

Comment: Thanks Varun, "However, gzip does not have such a technique and therefore this cannot be sent to different mappers." -- is there any Hadoop document claims that?

Comment: As I stated, it is not possible to decompress gzip in parallel, unless you have already decompressed that same file once serially and built a map of entry points _or_ the gzip file has been specially prepared for parallel decompression, which requires custom software for that purpose.

Comment: @Varun Shingal does one has to add bzip2 to hadoop in order to use it or does it come shipped with hadoop by default? thanx!

Comment: @theexplorer Hadoop has supported this, by default I think, since release 0.21.0 in 2010.  It's great.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-4012

Answer (score 2):

You can look a [pbzip2](http://compression.ca/pbzip2/) for an example of parallel bz2 compression and decompression.

There is a parallel gzip as well, [pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz/).  It does parallel compression, but not parallel decompression.  The deflate format is not suited to parallel decompression. However you can either a) prepare a special gzip stream with resets of the history, or b) you can build an index into a gzip file on the first pass.  Either way, you can then read different parts in parallel, or have more efficient random access.

Comment: Thanks Mark for providing detailed information. Actually what I am asking is how to work with bzip2 and gzip format on Hadoop. For example, how to use multiple mappers to read one bzip2 file in parallel in multiple mappers.

Comment: I figured that.  You can get a start by seeing how it's done in C.

Comment: I am not sure Hadoop has built-in function to support multiple mappers to read one bzip2 or gzip file in parallel?